# How to use Ext.Net RadioGroup control in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I am learning to use [Ext.Net](http://examples.ext.net/). I cannot find a way to display an Ext.net RadioGroup items vertically. Even when I set `Vertical="true"`, the RadioGroup is not displayed vertically.

**Please see a sample markup:**

```
<ext:Panel ID="PanelDaily" runat="server" Title="Daily">
    <Items>
        <ext:RadioGroup ID="RadioGroup2"  runat="server" Vertical="true">
            <Items>
                <ext:Radio ID="Radio1" FieldLabel="" runat="server" BoxLabel="Every Hour(s)" Checked="true"/>
                <ext:Radio ID="Radio2" FieldLabel="" runat="server" BoxLabel="At" />
            </Items>
        </ext:RadioGroup>
    </Items>
</ext:Panel>
```

How to diplay an Ext.net RadioGroup control items vertically?

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `asp.net-mvc`?

Comment: Similar question, why is it tagged with extjs?

Answer (score 1):

The `.Vertical` property is used in conjunction with the `.ColumnsNumber` property. Setting `Vertical="true"` affects how the Items are distributed in the Columns during Render.

From the ExtJS docs:

[Ext.form.RadioGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-cfg-vertical)

> True to distribute contained controls across columns, completely
>   filling each column top to bottom before starting on the next column.
>   The number of controls in each column will be automatically calculated
>   to keep columns as even as possible. The default value is false, so
>   that controls will be added to columns one at a time, completely
>   filling each row left to right before starting on the next row.

The following simple diagrams demonstrate the difference in the ordering of Items within the Columns.

```
// ColumnsNumber="2"
// Vertical="false" <-- default value

1    6
2    7
3    8 
4    9 
5

// ColumnsNumber="2"
// Vertical="true"

1    2
3    4
5    6
7    8
9
```

Here's a full sample demonstrating use of the `.ColumnsNumber` and `.Vertical` properties.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:Panel 
        runat="server" 
        Title="Example" 
        Width="350" 
        Height="215"
        Padding="5">
        <Items>
            <ext:RadioGroup runat="server" ColumnsNumber="2" Vertical="true">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Purple" />
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Yellow" />
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Green" />
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Blue" />
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Red" />
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Orange" />
                    <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Black" />
                </Items>
            </ext:RadioGroup>
        </Items>
    </ext:Panel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.